# Are there known issues on DNS propogation with unusual top-level domains?

Tags: domain-name-system

Trying to set-up simple A record for example.**software** domain. I'm finding that the DNS isn't propagating for a large number of locations. We changed the registrar recently. Originally it was registered on Google domains, and I believe it had propagated correctly with that registrar.

How can I get my domain to properly propagate globally?

[image: DNS Check]

Comment: It'd help a lot if you gave the actual domain.

Comment: Domain is 'dynatrace.software'.

Comment: there's no such a thing as "propagation" in DNS

Comment: Google search disagrees with you. @poige
https://www.ecosia.org/search?tt=0e30b125&q=dns%20propagation

Comment: Doesn't matter; DNS still does not "propagate" despite that this is so common a misconception that it has search results.

Comment: @AndrewKnackstedt That there are result for "lizard people" on Google doesn't mean lizard people actually exist. DNS doesn't propagate. It simply doesn't work that way. It has behavior that somewhat *looks like* propagation because of caching at various levels.

Comment: Also, changing registrar is different than changing DNS providers. Those are two separate jobs. By default a "pure" registrar change does not change anything at the DNS level. Of course, if you use the registrar as DNS provider then things collide. Also, did you ask your "registrar" about your issue?

Comment: The issue with resolution has been ongoing for months, we tried moving the registration to NSOne to see if it might fix the DNS resolution globally. We suspect there might be a problem as it's an unusual .software domain.

Answer (score 3):

You've recently changed DNS-provider/registrar. This means that it'll take some time before every TTL that's cached globally expires and servers starts fetching it from the root again. This can take a couple of days sometimes.

The domain seems completely resolvable to me when you go through the root:

```
~$ dig +trace +additional dynatrace.software A

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.2-Ubuntu <<>> +trace +additional dynatrace.software A
;; global options: +cmd
.                       509513  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       509513  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       509513  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       509513  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       509513  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       509513  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       509513  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       509513  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       509513  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       509513  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       509513  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       509513  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       509513  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       509513  IN      RRSIG   NS 8 0 518400 20201108050000 20201026040000 26116 . AIyLJv3h6m2S1Mflw1EviuvKCL6JKWghxOYjPQEGvsGNS0YOsF+qvJc1 l7Zt1J6/GYi1q7Nd8GbvTmp7DAkrrETqYKSIBWeqChEl8JoXtFW3W8tA tHFZenJkV1SPIJqlMO96AquCfmlLIY0Yph58sQHUDFljFl1yy6EMrQZc +0ATIKzibX9fhIya4VIvxROP/XdpSTjzWZVRuzP1Fv3eLiuOhizpz0GW +nF5QBzD0VDz0PqSoZ+EbFvhScwbPH5FT3G98TNdbG6VvgOLpELohsPw HPZmD6OY7N8GoedQ5XyZEG1+goS7eXi0PnRmvNfYPXYx0ImIBtjoFo/F 0mjc/A==
;; Received 525 bytes from 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1) in 10 ms

software.               172800  IN      NS      demand.beta.aridns.net.au.
software.               172800  IN      NS      demand.alpha.aridns.net.au.
software.               172800  IN      NS      demand.delta.aridns.net.au.
software.               172800  IN      NS      demand.gamma.aridns.net.au.
software.               86400   IN      DS      12949 8 1 06C5968D23178124399C5183401EC634FCAA883D
software.               86400   IN      DS      12949 8 2 AAC790B10ACECB01EBC34DD96D15DBD34F528E0E331AED376AD8EDC4 13FDD5BE
software.               86400   IN      RRSIG   DS 8 1 86400 20201108050000 20201026040000 26116 . SLDfPqZTotoQRKVUpBYzKTl9vvEG5vmDdUBw3HSh8bw4BRhmf61zvZAG K2RS2Eazsz9jtSMfHEjYQjFpyaoP3GElliEnfMEyip+4cUYu9VMFw4us kHF1dckIJvk13aw7sgiJLaq7X3S8TQgY2P/gZ/uIs+xazaPJIbdJ32r5 5FioBeH8HlmG4S7vOBbdjIKjyEXeCxba9Xu1Jwur/B+ZlKLGzbFLPYyD inU0SnC+tUWTSDLKsXjqtBTBU7cNxygJcucuRDxip98qn6MQgqoJAPOL z5mQVJD/WduupQPwuLWCzPUAtmckRT4UF9+Ik8s8out76LsIL5vUp54S On8j2w==
demand.beta.aridns.net.au. 172800 IN    A       37.209.194.7
demand.alpha.aridns.net.au. 172800 IN   A       37.209.192.7
demand.delta.aridns.net.au. 172800 IN   A       37.209.198.7
demand.gamma.aridns.net.au. 172800 IN   A       37.209.196.7
demand.beta.aridns.net.au. 172800 IN    AAAA    2001:dcd:2::7
demand.alpha.aridns.net.au. 172800 IN   AAAA    2001:dcd:1::7
demand.delta.aridns.net.au. 172800 IN   AAAA    2001:dcd:4::7
demand.gamma.aridns.net.au. 172800 IN   AAAA    2001:dcd:3::7
;; Received 714 bytes from 198.97.190.53#53(h.root-servers.net) in 28 ms

dynatrace.software.     86400   IN      NS      dns1.p06.nsone.net.
dynatrace.software.     86400   IN      NS      dns2.p06.nsone.net.
dynatrace.software.     86400   IN      NS      dns3.p06.nsone.net.
dynatrace.software.     86400   IN      NS      dns4.p06.nsone.net.
dynatrace.software.     86400   IN      DS      19829 8 2 1B1FCC6BBF3A2B8EB5BAB887833552546E17B68208B38A3A71E94380 4EEC07ED
dynatrace.software.     86400   IN      RRSIG   DS 8 2 86400 20201125044140 20201026035514 15000 software. pSjHVMs/cWhMMkVBqRwBNIxzkH96NlWl0MGvusTqahQRHlmNlt0oBd4M BvAii60NiUWKc4rc3qTvTBlccH4A8LVCnPOG1uYjTGWc84ryrD7kqk1F hEb7HD8XC0F4RloUuriKDV/LyKMRGcZ7QkezGECZ1JH9iCWyBFyWXIAB THLOPbm+LNWlAQFEN2S0MDzsWl05Zt42AhIvj3p2Q8DrXA==
;; Received 384 bytes from 37.209.198.7#53(demand.delta.aridns.net.au) in 14 ms

dynatrace.software.     3600    IN      A       35.201.104.155
;; Received 63 bytes from 198.51.44.6#53(dns1.p06.nsone.net) in 41 ms
```

Comment: We changed it Friday around noon, so I figured most of the DNS resolution servers should have requested a new record by now.